# Not able to write the testcases for inner class using EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I am new to the EasyMock. I need to test my class using the EasyMock. but here the problem is my class has inner class and this inner class is instatiated in the outer class's method and calling the method of inner class by passing some parameters. I am not sure how to write the test case for this scenario.

Please help me write the test case for this.

Any help or suggetions are highly appreciated.

```
public class ServiceClass implements ServiceInterface {

   public void updateUSer(USer) {
      //some logic over here.
      sendEmailNotice(subject, vTemplate);
   }

   private sendEmailNotice(subject, vTemplate) {

       MimeMessagePrepator eNotice = new PrepareEmailNotice(subject, vTemplate);
       MailSender.send( eNotice );   
   }

   public class PrepareEmailNotice implements MimeMessagePrepator {
       // some local variables.
       public PrepareEmailNotice(subject, vTemplate) {
          subject = subject;
          vTemplate = vTemplate;
       }

       public void prepare( MimeMessage message) {
          MimeMessageHealper helper = new MimeMessageHealper(message, true);
          // setting the mail properties like subject, to address, etc..
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code you've given isn't valid - you haven't specified types for some of your parameters. It's also not clear what you're trying to mock here - what dependency are you interested in?

Comment: Jon, All the parameters specified in the code (subject, vTemplate) are Strings. I am looking for the solution like how to mock the inner class and how to get that inner class methods cover in the unit testing.

Comment: Are you sure you need to mock the inner class rather than something the inner class uses (such as the `MimeMessageHealper`)? Think about what you *really* want the dependencies to be - once you've worked that out, you should mock out those dependencies.

Comment: I left a possible test to this class here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510453/how-to-test-the-inner-classes-by-using-easymock

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to think about what is the class responsibility.
At should it be doing with who should it be speaking?

Once you've clearly identified the dependencies you need to see how you can handle them in your code.
You might need do to perform some refactoring in order to conform to the dependency inversion principle.
For example here you have a dependency to the MailSender class but you won't be able to mock it as this dependency is "hard coded".

There is a good video about that: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcT4yYu_TTs